# python setup.py py2app raises [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, cmd, dmg

I'm sorry if this is very obvious but I am trying to convert a .py to a .dmg This is the tutorial I followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IIAlkQEw8Gc
I ran `python setup.py py2app`. I did everything that was in the video: I installed py2app, I created a setup.py in the same directory as my .py file with the piece of code that was in the video.
I really don't know what to do, can you help me? (total noob action here!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see I think you need to download the file to get on with coding